# Swift and Objective-C code analysis and style tool

Tags: osx, code-analysis, code-beautification, code-review, swift

I'm looking for a tool to help the automation of best practices for Swift and iOS.  One that can learn and enforce best practices, and enforce code style based on a set of custom or preset rules.  The tool should detect bad indentation, when delegates or weak references are not nil'd out on `deinit`, use of syntax (`Array<Element>` vs `[Element]`), etc.

I've looked at both [Faus Pas](http://fauxpasapp.com/) (Obj-C only) and [Code Climate](https://codeclimate.com/) (web-based), but I'm looking for a program that works specifically with Swift, can be installed locally on our development machines, and can be integrated as a build step with Jenkins or CircleCI.

I'm potentially evaluating the analysis tools provided with [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/), but I'm not sure how well they work with Swift.  [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) looks like exactly what I want, is there a Swift equivalent?

I've modified my question slightly to include support for a mixed codebase containing both Objective-C and Swift (and potentially Objective-C++).  The tools I have found previously only currently support Swift.  As an alternative, I will also accept answers that use tools for each language that integrate nicely.

Comment: Doesn't satisfy the request out of the box, but could be customized to do arbitrary style checks: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/30370/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) and [Tailor](http://tailor.sh/), which both enforce Swift style and convention best practices.

Both can be run from the command line as an external tool, or integrated with Xcode.

Both are well-maintained and Tailor is cross-platform.  Both have customizable rules engines.

Tailor looks more "official," with a more stable dev team, but it's hard to say which tool is objectively "better."

I'm leaning more towards SwiftLint, as it gives you the ability to configure rules as well as specific project directories to lint from a YAML file in your project directory.

As far as Objective-C tools compatible with Swift, JP Simard, the author of SwiftLint, [suggested](https://twitter.com/simjp/status/666339389442621440) using [Clang Format](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) as as similar tool for Objective-C in hybrid projects.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at:

- [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) - Gratis & Open Source
- [Atom Linter](https://github.com/atom-community/linter) + [SwiftC](https://atom.io/packages/linter-swiftc) plugin - Also Gratis & Open Source but requires [Atom](https://atom.io/) so may not suit your usage.